# After creating separate Models and Controllers projects, I get "no suitable method found to override" on my Initialize method declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, projects

This is driving me insane... I am reorganizing my MVC app into a Models project and a Controllers project, and then the main application as a project.  So, everything is working good so far except...

Whenever I go to "Rebuild" my controllers project, I get this error:

Controllers.AccountController.Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)': no suitable method found to override.

Keep in mind that AccountController.cs was automatically placed in my application by Visual Studio, and this was all working fine when the Controllers were within my main project.  I think it might have to do with the ASPNETDB.MDF file that this AccountController.cs file references to authenticate users as they log in, since this database stayed within my main project and didn't follow the Controllers project.  Thoughts on that??

Here's the Initialize method on my AccountController:

```
        protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (FormsService == null) { FormsService = new FormsAuthenticationService(); }
        if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(); }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

PLEASE HELP!!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is your AccountController inheriting from? It can't find a method with the same signature anywhere above this class in the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out what I was missing was a reference to System.Web.Routing.  I had `using System.Web.Routing`, and it wasn't marked "red" (meaning, it couldn't find it), so I just assumed it was there.  So this fixed the problem.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer. u should give it through add comment.

Comment: This is actually the solution to the problem I was having... How is this not an answer?

Answer (score 1):

this error message suggests that your AccountController class isn't being derived from MVC's Controller base class.